# Visual Studio Tools For Office (Excel 2016 Workbook) Designer Showing Blue Screen

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2017, vsto, excel-2016

So I'm trying to start a VSTO Excel Workbook project and cannot seem to get the designer to actually open the spreadsheet I've seeded the project with.

The designer just shows a blue screen and doesn't let me actually edit the spreadsheet.

This also occurs when I start a fresh project from scratch.

I have no issue editing the code for each sheet or the workbook as a whole, it's just the designer that's giving me issues.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with Excel 2016.

Thoughts?

[Designer Blue Screen Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C677C.png)

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the latest updates for Visual Studio and Office?

Comment: Yes, I have installed all the latest updates. I can't imagine this has to do with the fact that it's a .xlsm, does it?

Comment: Do you have the Office Developer Tools installed? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/office-tools/

Answer (score 2):

In your Windows display settings, try setting your monitor's "scale and layout" settings to 100%.

Comment: That sadly is the answer. Visual Studio is not compatible with common/recommended settings for 4K displays.